# Execution order of Javascript Events in JSF Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable with a `<p:rowEditor />`. The Logic of my process is when i click on a button it's suppose to:

1. Jump to the **last page** of the Datatable
2. Refresh the table
3. Click on the **edit button** of the last row

in the footer i implemement a commandButton and remoteCommand looking like:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <p:remoteCommand name="rctype" update="typeDT" 
     actionListener="#{myView.onNewType}" />
    <p:commandButton id="btnNewType" ajax="true" onclick="rctype()"
     update="typeDT" icon="ui-icon-plus" title="New Type" 
     value="New Type" >
    </p:commandButton>
</f:facet>
```

**my Bean** looks like :

```
public void onNewType() {
    try {
        ...
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('widgettypeDT')
         .paginator.setPage(PF('widgetinitiatorDT').paginator.cfg.pageCount - 1)");

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .execute("jQuery('.typeClass')
                    .find('span.ui-icon-pencil').last().click();");
    } catch() {}
}
```

But unfortunatly the **Click Event** always occur before the **Jump Event**.

How can i control the Execution order of my Javascript Events in my Managed Bean?

Comment: tried reversing them?

Comment: unfortunatly it doesnt work!

Comment: @BalusC: Sure this 'duplicate' matches the question? I tend to think it does not or just partially. These are 'javascript' calls

Comment: OP incorrectly interpreted onclick to behave as oncomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Call one javascript function on the client and do both in there. Or do both in one RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(...)

Comment: Already tried it too! With the same result!! The Click Event always occurs before the Jump Event

Comment: Thanks for mentioning you already tried that. In that case what you describe is not what actually happens but it is what you observe

Comment: Thx! this is the reason, why i do not understand the current behavior. I also tried delay... same result or an error occurs.